# Database design: Year table normalization

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

i have multiple table which include year column. I need a opinion which method is good ?

First Method:
each table has its own year column like this 
[image]

Second Method:
Create a separate table for year and add a foreign key like this
[image]

In future my database contain millions of record. So tell me which method is consider as a Best Practice ?

Comment: in the "years" table - can you have the same year multiple times? Because in your case I wouldn't recommend the years table. Think about it this way - it will only make your design and code more complicated

Comment: Is there some corellation between citation and decision? There's no need to have the joined table otherwise. Especially if years have to be unique.

Comment: No. i am planning to add years from 1947 to 2014. So in years table 67 rows are inserted.

Comment: There's no need for the third table then. I'd go with the first method.

Comment: citation and decision are non-correlated.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me to make decision.

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice would be "Don't replace a meaningful integer with a meaningless integer."